# Standard way to create DynamoDB or other stateful resources via CDK or cloudformation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a CDK package, where I want a SNS, a lambda and a DynamoDB. Now, the SNS and lambda being stateless can be generated using the CDK package.

So that would mean that a change in code, would require the whole package to be deployed again, and that would mean that the SNS is created again.

If I do that for DynamoDB, I think I will lose data that is stored in it, as it would be re-created.

Wanted to understand what is the standard way to create stateful resources with CDK.

Comment: Depends what you change in your DynamoDB. Some changes are replacement of resource, while others don't.

Comment: Let's say I don't change anything for DDB, but make a change somewhere else. Would that create a new resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you want to use `removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN` on your DynamoDb resource.
Let's say that your table name is `mytable`. Then a CDK implementation in Javascript(adjust it to your favourite language) will probably look like this:

```js
const { RemovalPolicy } = require("aws-cdk-lib");
const { AttributeType, Table } = require("aws-cdk-lib/aws-dynamodb");
const { Construct } = require("constructs");

class Database extends Construct {
    
    constructor(scope, id) {
        super(scope, id);
        this.myTable = this.createMyTable();
    }

    createMyTable() {
        const myTable = new Table(this, 'myTable', {
            partitionKey: {
                name: 'id',
                type: AttributeType.STRING
            },
            tableName: 'myTable',
            removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.RETAIN, // <----- Make sure to retain your old table on destroy
        });
    
        return myTable;
    };
}

module.exports = { Database };
```

Answer (score 2):

CloudFormation doesnt delete dynamodb tables by default. Altough its recommended to keep them in separate stack so you wont delete them by accident. See replace policy docs. You can also create stack IAM policy to disable deletion of dynamodb to be extra sure

Comment: Just to add to this... CloudFormation won't delete and replace resources unless you've changed something about it that requires a replacement. This is usually pretty rare and is usually just when you change the name or encryption settings (although it varies from resource to resource). Just doing another "deploy" of the stack won't necessarily delete and recreate anything.